# version-range tag unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Today I found [version-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-range). Currently there are in total 6 questions with this tag. It looks like they are all Maven questions. Unfortunately there is no tag wiki (yet). If the intended use is to mark questions specifically about the [Maven version ranges](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges) I'd suggest renaming it [maven-version-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-version-range). But I see a very limited use case for this tag. So unless I am missing other uses I'd say delete it.

Comment: Except for 1 question, the remaining all were related to [maven]. Given that the tag was being used just superfluously, I just poofed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that those questions should just be [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) + [dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency).  The current that seems too limited to be useful.

Comment: Why would we need [tag:dependency]? Versions are an integral part of Maven. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Those questions are about managing version dependencies.  Although, I now think [dependency-management] is probably better for these questions.